# HardonCollider Error: attempt to call method 'addRectangle' (a nil value)

Tags: collision-detection, lua, love2d

I want to add collision detection mechanism to my game, which is written in [love2d](https://love2d.org/). As i do not want to implement my own algorithm, i have found a [HardonCollider](https://vrld.github.io/HardonCollider/) library to do the heavy lifting for me.

I have followed the example code of the library but got an error even with a basic setup.

```
local hc  = require "hardoncollider"

local hero
local collider

function on_collision(dt, shape_a, shape_b, mtv_x, mtv_y)

end

function love.load(arg)
    collider = hc(100, on_collision)
    hero = collider:addRectangle(30,30,16,16)
end
```

Running this code will throw the following error message:

```
PS C:\dev\love-0.10.0-win64> Error: main.lua:12: attempt to call method 'addRectangle' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        main.lua:12: in function 'load'
        [string "boot.lua"]:437: in function 
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I have been investigating the problem, but did not find any solutions nor anybody else who faced this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here, in case somebody else encounters this issue.

Looks like i have been reading outdated documentation & samples, according to the [new docs](http://hc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) there is no such method as `addRectangle`.

It should be:

```
collider = hc.new(100, on_collision)
hero = collider:rectangle(30,30,16,16)
```

Answer (score 1):

`addRectangle` is a method of hardoncollider, not a method of the object produced from running `hc(100, on_collision)`. The correct way to do this would be:

```
function love.load(arg)
collider = hc(100, on_collision)
hero = hc:addRectangle(30,30,16,16)
end
```

Comment: I don't know why this is being upvoted, but the suggested solution does not work. running the updated code produces the same error message.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you weren't running the linked version.